# Multiple Joins on Temporary Table OR Subquery in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, join, temp-tables

I have the following SQL which gets a season for each day in a range of dates, then groups each season by start and end date with number of nights. What it does is not important but my question is which is better, the way I've done it below or use the first select statement as a subquery each time @dateSeasons is used in the second query. Both ways seem to run the same but this way looks neater.

```
DECLARE @dateSeasons TABLE ([date] date, seasonID int)

INSERT INTO @dateSeasons
SELECT D.[date], S.ID
FROM @dates AS D
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM dbo.Seasons
    WHERE bookingID = @bookingID 
    AND D.[date] BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
    ORDER BY ID DESC

) AS S


SELECT MIN([date]), endDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([date]), DATEADD(DAY, 1, endDate)), seasonID
FROM (

    SELECT S1.seasonID, S1.[date], (

        SELECT MAX([date])
        FROM @dateSeasons S2
        WHERE S2.seasonID = S1.seasonID
        AND NOT EXISTS (

            SELECT NULL
            FROM @dateSeasons S3
            WHERE S3.[date] < S2.[date]
            AND S3.[date] > S1.[date]
            AND S3.seasonID <> S1.seasonID

        )

    ) AS endDate
    FROM @dateSeasons S1
) AS results
GROUP BY endDate, seasonID
ORDER BY MIN([date])
```

Comment: "What it does is not important" - I think you'll it is! Often, people will tell you their perceived solution to a problem rather than the actual problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah obviously it's important to me but it's not important to the question I'm asking.

Comment: Which is better is going to be highly dependent on the specific RDBMS, table structures, indexes, and the size distribution of your data. None of these are specified in your question. The best way to determine which of two queries is better is usually to test them against each other while watching whatever query statistics and query plans your RDBMS makes available to you.

As to Mitch's comment and your response, it's usually important because the answer to which is better will often be, "none of the above".

Comment: +1 Tom.  @CL4NCY, what Mich and Tom are saying is, if you are bothering to post here, you probably should let these guys help determine what is important and what isn't.  Something you think is minor could be vitally important to the query execution plan in  your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking neater is **irrelevant** in writing SQL Code. What looks elegant is often the **worst** possible way to solve the problem from a performance standpoint.

The only way to know for sure which is best is to first make sure both ways you are testing return the same results and then performance test them and check out the execution plans (or explain in mySQL). Techniques which make the query better are database specific as well. What works best to performance tune in SQL Server might be the worst possibility in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get better performance by using a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (CTE):

```
WITH
dateSeasons ([date], [seasonID])
AS
(
    SELECT D.[date], S.ID
    FROM @dates AS D
    CROSS APPLY (

        SELECT TOP 1 ID
        FROM dbo.Seasons
        WHERE bookingID = @bookingID 
        AND D.[date] BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        ORDER BY ID DESC

    ) AS S
)

SELECT MIN([date]), endDate, DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN([date]), DATEADD(DAY, 1, endDate)), seasonID
FROM (

    SELECT S1.seasonID, S1.[date], (

        SELECT MAX([date])
        FROM dateSeasons S2
        WHERE S2.seasonID = S1.seasonID
        AND NOT EXISTS (

            SELECT NULL
            FROM dateSeasons S3
            WHERE S3.[date] < S2.[date]
            AND S3.[date] > S1.[date]
            AND S3.seasonID <> S1.seasonID

        )

    ) AS endDate
    FROM dateSeasons S1
) AS results
GROUP BY endDate, seasonID
ORDER BY MIN([date])
```

Comment: From my experience CTE works properly when the underlying tables are indexed properly. This is rarely the case (not because indexes are neglected, it's just as with everything in SQL , indexing is a balancing act), unless one works on well designed and internally consistent database, which - again, in my experience - would be a data repo built primarily. for reporting/analysis (marts, warehouses...). Nothing against CTE's but when in a tight spot it's the index that makes the difference. Just to keep in mind when going for this solution.